# JavaScript challenging form elements array validation

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have one HTML form:

```
<form name="modeladd" ethod="post" class="form label-inline" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return check('modeladd');">
            <?php  for($i=0;$i<$tot;$i++) { ?>      
                <div class="field">
                <label for="connect_msg">Connect Message </label>                                                                   
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="connect_msg[<?php echo getField($langs[$lan]);?>]" id="connect_msg[]"><?php echo getField($row[$lan]); ?></textarea>
                </div>              
                <div class="field">
                <label for="call_msg">Call Message :</label>                                                
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="call_msg[<?php echo getField($langs[$lan]);?>]" id="call_msg"><?php echo getField($row[$lan]); ?></textarea>
                </div>
                
                <div class="field">
                <label for="stripline_msg">Stripline Message :</label>                                              
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="stripline_msg[<?php echo getField($langs[$lan]);?>]" id="stripline_msg"><?php echo getField($row[$lan]); ?></textarea>
                </div>
            <div class="field">
                    <label for="cost_msg">Cost Message :</label>                                                
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="cost_msg[<?php echo getField($langs[$lan])?>]" id="cost_msg"><?php echo getField($row[$lan]); ?></textarea>
                </div>          
                <?php } ?>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-grey" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript for validation:

```
function check(form)
{
   var name = new Array();
   name =document.getElementById('connect_msg[]').value;

   for(var i=0 ; i<=1; i++)
   { 
      alert(name[i].value); 
   }
   return true;
}
```

I am not  getting value for both the `connect_msg` field which is array. I want to validate both the field value using JavaScript so please help me.

Comment: You can use only one element with the same ID.

Comment: yes that's why i have used array in connect_msg element

Answer (score 2):

1. The `id` cannot have `[]` symbols. Please validate your markup: http://validator.w3.org/
2. The `value` returned from an element is type `string`, so you can't get an array. What you can do is parse the string to create your array.

Eg. Assuming the following is the outputted markup:

```
<textarea id="connect_msg">a,b,c,d,e,f,g</textarea>
```

You can do this in JavaScript:

```
var getConnectMsg = document.getElementById('connect_msg').value;
var connectMsgArray = getConnectMsg.split(',');
```

And `connectMsgArray` will contain `['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']`.

You can read more about `.split()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

**Edit:** Since you say the `textarea` is in a loop, then it's more easier to retrieve the elements using `class` name attribute, and using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) will help you immensely.

So the HTML output would be like this:

```
<textarea class="connect_msg" id="connect_msg1">a,b,c,d,e,f,g</textarea>
<textarea class="connect_msg" id="connect_msg2">h,i,j,k,l,m,n</textarea>
<textarea class="connect_msg" id="connect_msg3">q,r,s,t,u,v</textarea>

var getConnectMsg = $('.connect_msg');
getConnectMsg.each(function(){
    var getValue = $(this).val();
    var connectMsgArray = getValue.split(',');
});
```

In each iteration of the `.each()`, the value of `getValue` would be:

```
 a,b,c,d,e,f,g
 h,i,j,k,l,m,n
 q,r,s,t,u,v
```

You can do your form validation for a set of fields during each iteration.

Comment: this taxtarea is in loop, so there is no single id=connect_msg possible, each textarea needs unique id,

Comment: Also, don't use `new Array();` since that will actually make the interpreter call the Array constructor and add unnecessary overhead. To create an array, simply add empty square brackets `var name = [];`

Answer (score 0):

the name can't be a multi-dimensional array change this:

```
name="connect_msg[<?php echo getField($langs[$lan]);?>]"
```

To this:

```
name="connect_msg[]"
```

And then address them in the post script with a foreach loop.
And about the id use this instead() I don't know if it's true that you can't use [] in the id but I know this worked for me:

```
id="connect_msg_<?php echo getField($langs[$lan]);?>"
```

**Update:**
I think your right, maybe using a class instead of id is the way to go.

```
class="connect_msg"
```

And then in the form check function instead of this:

```
var name = new Array();
name =document.getElementById('connect_msg[]').value;
```

Do this:

```
var connectMsg = document.getElementByClassName('connect_msg');
```

And then loop through the connectMsg array and get/validate the values.
Hope this help.

Comment: no it's working properly with name i want ID Element's value not  name thanks

Comment: id="connect_msg_<?php echo getField($langs[$lan]);?>" how do i get this element's value on form submit